# PostValue didn't update my Observer in MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have an activity to perform rest API everytime it opened and i use MVVM pattern for this project. But with this snippet code i failed to get updated everytime i open activity. So i debug all my parameters in every line, they all fine the suspect problem might when `apiService.readNewsAsync(param1,param2)` execute, my postValue did not update my `resulRead` parameter. There were no crash here, but i got result which not updated from result (postValue). Can someone explain to me why this happened?
Here what activity looks like

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityReadBinding>(this,
            R.layout.activity_read).apply {
            this.viewModel = readViewModel
            this.lifecycleOwner = this@ReadActivity
        }
        readViewModel.observerRead.observe(this, Observer {
            val sukses = it.isSuccess
            when{
                sukses -> {
                    val data = it.data as Read
                    val article = data.article
                    //Log.d("-->", "${article.toString()}")
                }
                else -> {
                    toast("ada error ${it.msg}")
                    Timber.d("ERROR : ${it.msg}")
                }
            }

        })
                readViewModel.getReadNews()
    }
```

**Viewmodel**

```
var observerRead = MutableLiveData<AppResponse>()

 init {
        observerRead = readRepository.observerReadNews()
    }


fun getReadNews() {

        // kanal and guid i fetch from intent and these value are valid

        loadingVisibility = View.VISIBLE
        val ok = readRepository.getReadNews(kanal!!, guid!!)
        if(ok){
            loadingVisibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
class ReadRepositoryImpl private constructor(private val newsdataDao: NewsdataDao) : ReadRepository{
    override fun observerReadNews(): MutableLiveData<AppResponse> {
        return newsdataDao.resultRead
    }

    override fun getReadNews(channel: String, guid: Int) = newsdataDao.readNews(channel, guid)

    companion object{
        @Volatile private var instance: ReadRepositoryImpl? = null

        fun getInstance(newsdataDao: NewsdataDao) = instance ?: synchronized(this){
            instance ?: ReadRepositoryImpl(newsdataDao).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL / DATA SOURCE**

```
class NewsdataDao {

    private val apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService::class.java)
    var resultRead = MutableLiveData<AppResponse>()

    fun readNews(channel: String, guid: Int): Boolean{
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val response = apiService.readNewsAsync(Constants.API_TOKEN, channel, guid.toString()).await()
            when{
                response.isSuccessful -> {
                    val res = response.body()
                    val appRes = AppResponse(true, "ok", res!!)
                    resultRead.postValue(appRes)
                }
                else -> {
                    val appRes = AppResponse(false, "Error: ${response.message()}", null)
                    resultRead.postValue(appRes)
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this activity is not getting stopped.

Check this out:
[image]

When you call `readViewModel.getReadNews()` in onCreate() your activity is created once, only if onStop is called will it be created again.

Comment: i didn't override anything on `onBackPressed()` method activity. Does it mean when i press back also invoking `onDestroy` event?

Comment: btw, i change the title with suitable one

Comment: Yeah it probably is.

Comment: How to recall onCreate() again? Observer always late to update, it will show news that i have opened before

Comment: Move your logic to onResume() it gets called every time. Or depending on your use case you can just add a function to your onCreate and put all your creation work there, and call it whenever you need to (probably not the best way).

Comment: after i move my observer to resume It's works! @Richard Dapice Thank you!!!